# Android: SQLite Query Return 0 Rows Without Reload?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

My application has a SQLite database to contain a list of highways.  It shows them all in a list.  It first tries to query the database for the roads.  If the query doesn't return any, it calls another method that downloads a list from a remote server, and populates the database.  After that returns, it immediately queries the database again.

That's how it should work.  How it actually works is, the first query *always* returns nothing.  It goes straight to downloading a fresh list, it inserts the list into the database, and queries again.  The second query always returns the correct result.  The strange thing is, I can repeat the operation without even exiting the application.  Using the `adb` shell, I can read the SQLite3 database on the emulator.  The data shown in the database is exactly as expected.  But the application is behaving as though the data isn't there?  Is there some behaviour I'm not aware of?  Here's the code.

`RoadsDataSource.java`

```
public class RoadsDataSource {

    private DataStorage data;

    private static Context context;

    public RoadsDataSource() {
        this.data = new DataStorage(RoadsDataSource.context);
    }

    private List<Road> getRoads(Integer state) {
        List<Road> roads = loadRoadsFromDb(state);
        if (roads.isEmpty()) {
            Request api = new Request(RoadsDataSource.context);
            Roads apiRoads = api.fetchRoads(state);
            this.data.storeRoads(apiRoads);
            roads = loadRoadsFromDb(state);
        }
        return roads;
    }

    private List<Road> loadRoadsFromDb(Integer state) {
        SQLiteQueryBuilder query = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        query.setTables(Queries.ROAD_STATE_MATCHES);
        Cursor results = query.query(
                this.data.getWritableDatabase(),
                new String[] {Tables.ROADS + "." + Tables.Roads.ID, Tables.ROADS + "." + Tables.Roads.TYPE, Tables.ROADS + "." + Tables.Roads.NUMBER}, 
                Queries.ROADS_BY_STATE,
                new String[] {state.toString()}, null, null, null 
        );

        List<Road> roads = new ArrayList<Road>();

        results.moveToFirst();
        while (!results.isAfterLast()) {
            roads.add(new Road(results.getInt(0), results.getString(1), results.getInt(2)));
            results.moveToNext();
        }
        results.close();

        System.out.println(roads.size());
        return roads;
    }
}
```

`DataStorage.java`

```
public class DataStorage extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public void storeRoads(Roads roads) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        for (Road road : roads.getRoads()) {
            ContentValues roadRow = new ContentValues();
            roadRow.put(Tables.Roads.ID, road.getId());
            roadRow.put(Tables.Roads.TYPE, road.getType());
            roadRow.put(Tables.Roads.NUMBER, road.getNumber());
            try {
                db.insertOrThrow(Tables.ROADS, null, roadRow);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            }
            ContentValues linkRow = new ContentValues();
            linkRow.put(Tables.StatesRoads.STATE_ID, roads.getState());
            linkRow.put(Tables.StatesRoads.ROAD_ID, road.getId());
            try {
                db.insertOrThrow(Tables.STATES_ROADS, null, linkRow);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with android's wrappers.  Insofar as sqlite in general, I would expect that behavior if a transaction was not completing.  I would also not allow those empty catches to pass a code review.  You're asking for weird behavior. :)

Comment: Concerning the empty catches, I'm in the early stages of development.  At this point, I'm just trying to get the functionality in place, then I'll go back and deal with things like Exceptions.

Comment: Just a few questions - but in loadRoads, shouldn't you be using getReadableDatabase() and closing the handle opened by the getWriteableDatabase call?

Comment: I suppose.  Could that be causing the problem?

Comment: I've had huge issues in the past with not closing the database handle - generally I do all db operations inside an SQLiteOpenHelper subclass, keeping a reference to the db, opening and closing it atomically

Comment: It seems that the problem was my fault and not a behaviour of Android.  During some previous debugging I had added a line to delete the database every time the `DataStorage` object was created.  I remove it, and it works perfectly.  All the same, @MoKargas, why don't you post what you said as an answer and I'll award you the bounty for trying to answer my question.

Comment: @MoKargas I'll award you the bounty, then I'll close the question since it wouldn't apply to anyone else.

Comment: No problem @Jonah, I'm glad you were able to solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had huge issues in the past with not closing the database handle - generally I do all db operations inside an SQLiteOpenHelper subclass, keeping a reference to the db, opening and closing it atomically.

Answer (score 2):

Mo Kargas is right.  Your db helper should look more like this http://code.google.com/p/android-notes/source/browse/trunk/src/com/bitsetters/android/notes/DBHelper.java?r=10

This may fix your issue though Replace

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
```

with this

```
SQLiteDatabase db;
try {
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
} catch (SQLiteException e) {
   db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
}
```